# How to automate bio-metric identification like face recognition and fingerprint?

Tags: android, appium, android-biometric

So I'm trying to automate an application end to end and it involves facial recognition to store the photo of user. The user can use the front camera/rear camera and within a few seconds it detects the facial features and store it. Is there any tool which can be used to verify this functionality or should I just use a stub to verify the integration?

Answer (score 0):

> implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1'

```
 private Executor executor;
    private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
    private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



      /*  BiometricManager biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this);
        switch (biometricManager.canAuthenticate()) {
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS:
                Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.");
                break;
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE:
                Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.");
                break;
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.");
                break;
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED:
                Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "The user hasn't associated " +
                        "any biometric credentials with their account.");
                break;
        }*/


                executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
        biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(MainActivity.this,
                executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                              @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Authentication error: " + errString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                    @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Authentication succeeded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
                .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
                .setNegativeButtonText("Use account password")
                .build();

        // Prompt appears when user clicks "Log in".
        // Consider integrating with the keystore to unlock cryptographic operations,
        // if needed by your app.
        Button biometricLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.biometric_login);
        biometricLoginButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have published a series of blog posts that walk you through integrating biometrics (fingerprint, face, etc) into your Android apps.

[Blog post 1](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html)

[Blog post 2](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd)

[Blog post 3](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-biometricprompt-with-cryptoobject-how-and-why-aace500ccdb7)